# Execute WordPress Plugin From Token?

Tags: php, wordpress, php-7

Ok, bear with me as I spend most of my days writing C#, JavaScript, HTML, etc. and not PHP.

I am trying to create a WordPress plugin.  I would like someone with edit rights to be able to place a token such as [[DONATIONFORM]] in the body of the page content. At runtime that token would be replaced with an actual form.

I have gotten as far as defining a plugin and having it show up in the list of plugins.   I have created a function in one of the plugin files called GenerateDonationForm().   I just don't know how to have it run when someone puts in a token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [shortcode api](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

From the docs:

> As a quick start for those in a hurry, here's a minimal example of the PHP code required to create a shortcode:

```
function foobar_func( $atts ){
    return "foo and bar";
}
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );
```

Make sure that your function returns the output, as opposed to echoing it!

Comment: This is the correct answer.   This page had information on the syntax if your plugin uses classes: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode